# IO.File.Delete Random UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: vb.net, file, exception, delete-file, unauthorized

I'm using My.Computer.Filesystem.WriteAllBytes to write out an executable stored in my application's resources to it's startup directory. After running the executable, I then delete it. Everything works fine; however, I'll randomly get an UnauthorizedAccessException for no reason. After getting the exception, I can manually delete the file with no problem. Here's the full code:

```
' Convert MP3
' First, copy out converter
Dim Path = New IO.FileInfo(SoundPath)
Try
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath + "\converter.exe", My.Resources.madplay, False)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Exit Sub
End Try
' Set up process
Dim MAD As New Process
' Set process info
Dim output As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Path.FullName) + ".wav"
Dim input As String = Path.FullName
Dim adjust As String = barVolumeAdjust.Value.ToString
Dim hz As String = "15000"
With (MAD.StartInfo)
    .FileName = Application.StartupPath + "\converter.exe"
    .Arguments = "-v -a " + adjust + " -R " + hz + " -o """ + output + """ """ + input + """"
    .UseShellExecute = False
    .RedirectStandardInput = True
    .RedirectStandardError = True
    .RedirectStandardOutput = True
    .CreateNoWindow = True
End With
' Start
MAD.Start()
' Update title with output
Dim Line As String = MAD.StandardError.ReadLine
While Not Line Is Nothing
    Me.Text = Line
    Line = MAD.StandardError.ReadLine
End While
' Stop
MAD.Close()
' Delete MAD
Try
    IO.File.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "\converter.exe")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End Try
```

What perplexes me is that I literally *just* wrote out the executable, and nothing else could possibly be using it. I've checked the file attributes and it's not read-only. My application is also running as an administrator. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not wait for the process to exit, so it is still running when you attempt to delete the file. See Process.[WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx)

Comment: Ah nice, I can't believe I overlooked that. I replaced MAD.Close() with MAD.WaitForExit() and all seems well! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your using a separate process to write out the file - perhaps this is still using the file when you try to delete.

I suggest catching and handling the exception to get around the problem.